# Integrability for double integral before applying Fubini's Theorem

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, or in another word $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\rvert f(x)\rvert dx < \infty$. Show $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h} |f(t)| \,dt\,dx < \infty$$
This inequality gives us the condition to apply Fubini's theorem to the double integral. But I am having difficulties to show the above inequality.

The first integral converges to $f(x)$ if $h\rightarrow 0$, but this perspective does not provide enough information to say about the integrability for the double integral.

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: I think you can treat the inner expression as a function - and then apply the dominated convergence theorem then FTC to get what you want